# Kubernetes pod (Java) restarts with 137 TERMINATED

Tags: java, kubernetes, restart

We are running Kubernetes (1.18) with Docker 1.19 & systemd on an on-prem deployment with 3 masters and 3 workers. OS is RedHat 7.8.

Container is a Java 13 based spring boot app (using base image as openjdk:13-alpine) and below are the memory settings.

Pod:

- memory - min 448M and max 2500M
- cpu - min 0.1

Container:

- Xms: 256M, Xmx: 512M

When traffic is send for a longer time, the container suddenly restarts; and in Prometheus I can see the Pod memory is below the max level (only around 1300MB).

In the pod events I can see warnings for liveness and readiness probes; and the pod getting restarted.

```
State:          Running
  Started:      Sun, 23 Aug 2020 15:39:13 +0530
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    137
  Started:      Sun, 23 Aug 2020 15:23:03 +0530
  Finished:     Sun, 23 Aug 2020 15:39:12 +0530
Ready:          True
Restart Count:  14
```

1. What are logs that I can refer to figure out why a restart was triggered? Application log is not helping at all; after the last log of the running app; I can see the starting line of the log as the next line.
2. What are the recommended approaches to troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: Edit the question to add pod yaml

Comment: It's a helm chart, and the docker image is for the microservice with above mentioned base. Any specific parameters needed?

Answer (score 0):

137 means 128 + 9 (so it was killed with *kill -9*)
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Have a look at the pod and application logs.

Maybe the container needs more resources to start?

Comment: Yes, and the container is running for hours with traffic. However, there is another microservice to which this one connects using RestTemplate, and it looks like that microservice is getting slower and slower when data is filling.

Comment: To me that indicates issues with the application and not k8s, but I have of course zero knowledge about the application you are operating

Comment: I got your point. What are the options in looking into the application level reasons; app log is useless as it does not have anything in between the crash & start; I already looked at a threaddupm and memorydump but can not see an issue. Is there any way of looking from a docker point of view?